# Patch external API call with two differents data set in Django command test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm testing a Django command which uses an external API named `redminelib`.

My mock class and patch in tests work pretty well but when I tried to patch command twice on same test with two different Mock instances, second command call use the first mock class instance.

Django command in `my_project/app/management/commands/redmine_command.py`:

```
from redminelib import Redmine


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        key = 'project'
        redmine_api_instance = Redmine({'user': 'pass'})
        redmine_project = redmine_api_instance.project.get(key)
        print(redmine_project)
```

In `my_project/app/tests.py`:

```
import unittest
import json

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import TestCase

class MockProject:
    """A project mock class"""
    def __init__(self, time_entries: list):
        self.time_entries = time_entries


class MockRedmine(unittest.mock.MagicMock):
   """Class who will mock the redminelib API"""
    # Define directory which contains data files 
    json_data_dir = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "app/testdata/")

    def __init__(self, json_project_file, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(json_project_file, *args, **kwargs)
        self.project = self.load(json_project_file)

    def load(self, json_file):
        json_filepath = os.path.join(MockRedmine.json_data_dir, json_file)
        with open(json_filepath, "r") as f:
            json_dict = json.load(f)
        project_dict = {key: MockProject(values) for key, values in json_dict.items()}
        return project_dict

# I test some case like this it works:
class TestCommand(TestCase):
    def test_invoice_creation_amount_and_update(self):
        with unittest.mock.patch("redminelib.Redmine") as redmine_mock_inst:
            mock_redmine = MockRedmine("api_case.json")
            redmine_mock_inst.return_value = mock_redmine
            call_command("my_command")
```

Now I use two differents data set: `api_case.json` and `other_api_case.json`:

```
class TestCommadTwice(TestCase):
    def test_invoice_creation_amount_and_update(self):
        with unittest.mock.patch("redminelib.Redmine") as redmine_mock_inst1:
            mock_redmine1 = MockRedmine("api_case.json")
            redmine_mock_inst1.return_value = mock_redmine1
            call_command("redmine_command")

        with unittest.mock.patch("redminelib.Redmine") as redmine_mock_inst:
            mock_redmine = MockRedmine("other_api_case.json")
            redmine_mock_inst.return_value = mock_redmine
            call_command("redmine_command")
```

I expect redmine_command output `MockRedmine("api_case.json")` then `MockRedmine("other_api_case.json")` but I have `MockRedmine("api_case.json")` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `unittest.mock.patch("app.management.commands.redmine_command.Redmine")`.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

> target should be a string in the form 'package.module.ClassName'. The
>   target is imported and the specified object replaced with the new
>   object, so the target must be importable from the environment you are
>   calling patch() from. The target is imported when the decorated
>   function is executed, not at decoration time.

Also, take a look at `Where to patch` section at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id5.